# How to take a Ubuntu system running in kiosk mode on remote outside the local environment

Tags: command-line, 18.04, scripts, remote-desktop, kiosk

I am running a cefpython application in kiosk mode on ubuntu 18.04. I want to take it on remote which is outside of local environment. I tried the port forwarding which is unsuccessful due to router.

I used [teleconsole](https://www.teleconsole.com/) to take on remote it is successful but when i run in kiosk mode it failed because session got closed. Can you tell how to keep this session alive till the machine is running.

To run the ubuntu in kiosk mode i used two scripts placed at /usr/share/xsession/ location

**kiosk.desktop**

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Pulse Mode
Comment=Pulse Kiosk Mode
Exec=/usr/share/xsessions/pulsekiosk.sh
Type=Application
```

**pulsekiosk.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
xset s off
xset s noblank
nm-applet &
sleep 5s
while true; do
    sh /booth/run.sh;
    sleep 5s;
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use stunnel to connect from clients to servers, then you have open SSH sessions to all of them:

Man page: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/stunnel4.8.html

Likewise, you could wo with VPN, eg. OpenVPN. Again, establish tunnel from your clients to your central server, then push traffic through it, and you can then ssh as usual to clients (but using the client's VPN IP)

Man page: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/man8/openvpn.8.html

This is a tutorial explaining both in pretty good details: https://medium.com/@jayden.chua/stunnel-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-18-04-1837eaf2077d

It would help to know if your server is behind NAT as well, or just the clients. Plus, perhaps just solving the NAT issue to properly configure it.